# Como obter todas as linhas usando valor duplicado no IN

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Como faço para obter todas as linhas usando IN(), e dentro do IN() ter valores duplicados

```
SELECT NOME FROM PESSOA WHERE ID IN (1,1,1,2,3,3,4)
```

Eu quero que no retorno venha 3 vezes o nome do ID 1, e 2 vezes o nome do ID 3.

Comment: Você não pode usar o `IN` para isto. Vai ter que montar uma *query* mais complexa.

Comment: @bigown, tem alguma ideia de como realizar esse select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei uma maneira, mais complexa, mas acho que é o jeito

```
SELECT NOME FROM PESSOA WHERE ID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT NOME FROM PESSOA WHERE ID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT NOME FROM PESSOA WHERE ID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT NOME FROM PESSOA WHERE ID = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT NOME FROM PESSOA WHERE ID = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT NOME FROM PESSOA WHERE ID = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT NOME FROM PESSOA WHERE ID = 4
```

Eu consigo fazer um script pra gerar o SQL baseado nos valores do `IN` então não vai ser muito difícil, só trabalhoso mesmo...